# Why isn't $\langle a ; a^2 \rangle$ (or $\langle a;a^3, a^7\rangle$) a presentation of $C_4$?

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups, free-groups, group-presentation

I've just read the first few pages of [*Combinatorial Group Theory*](http://books.google.com/books/about/Combinatorial_Group_Theory.html?id=1LW4s1RDRHQC) by Magnus, Karrass, and Solitar, and based on their definitions there, and more specifically, the reasoning given in the hint to exercise $5$(c) (on p. 9), I don't see why $\langle a ; a^2 \rangle$ (or even $\langle a ; a \rangle$, for that matter) shouldn't be regarded as a presentation of $C_4$.

Exercise $4$ (also on p. 9), asks the reader to establish that "if the word $K$ is derivable from the relators $M, N, \dots,$ and $M, N, \dots$ are derivable from the relators $P, Q, R, \dots,$ then $K$ is derivable from $P, Q, R, \dots\,$".

Exercise $5$(b) asks the reader to establish that $\langle a; a^4 \rangle$ is a presentation of $C_4$.  The sequence below

$$a^4,a^4a^{-2},a^2,a^2a^{-2},1$$

...shows that the word $a^4$ is derivable (using the operations stipulated on p. 6) from the relator $a^2$ (and is hence itself a relator).

Of course, I realize that $\langle a; a^2 \rangle$ is also a presentation of $C_2$, and that $C_2 \neq C_4$.

And pretty much the same reasoning would lead one to conclude that $\langle a; a^2 \rangle$ is a presentation of $C_{2n}$, and $\langle a; a \rangle$ is a presentation of $C_n$, for *any* $n \in \{2, 3, \dots\}$.  If so, a presentation of a group $G$ could not be considered (necessarily) a description, or specification, of $G$; so what's its purpose?

Therefore, I conclude that something must be missing, either from the authors' definition of a group presentation (p. 7)<sup>1</sup>, or from my grasp of it.

EDIT: To clarify, let me say more about the origin of my question, namely the hint to exercise $5$(c) (already alluded to at the beginning of this post).

Exercise $5$(c) asks

> Give a presentation for [the cyclic group of order 4] using one generating symbol $b$ and two defining relators, neither of which is $b^4$ or $b^{-4}$.

The hint for this question says:

> ...use $b^8$ and $b^{12}$ as defining relators, and show that $b^4$ can be derived.  Hence, by [exercise 4, cited above], $b^8$ and $b^{12}$ are a set of defining relators.

I have no problem following this hint, but I can just as well carry out exactly the same steps not just for $(b^8, b^{12})$, but for *any* pair $(b^n, b^{n+4})$ with $n \in \mathbb{Z} \backslash \{-1, 0, 1\}$, like so:  $$b^4,b^4b^n,b^{n+4},b^{n+4}b^{-(n+4)},1$$

And if this maneuver somehow renders $\langle b; b^n, b^{n+4}\rangle$ (for any $n \in \mathbb{Z} \backslash \{-1, 0, 1\}$) a presentation for $G$, then a similar maneuver would render $\langle a; a^2\rangle$, and even $\langle a; a\rangle$ a presentation for $G$.

I realize that this conclusion is nonsense.  I'm trying pinpoint the misstep in the reasoning.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> For completeness, this definition goes like this: "A word $R(a, b, c)$ which defines the identity element $1$ in [a group] $G$ is called a *relator*.  … If every relator [of a group $G$] is derivable from the relators $P, Q, R, \dots,$ then we call $P, Q, R, \dots$ a *set of defining relators* or a *complete set of relators* for the group $G$ on the generators $a, b, c, \dots .$  If $P, Q, R,\dots$ is a set of definitng relators fro the group G on the generators $a, b, c,\dots$ we call $$\langle a, b, c, \dots; P(a, b, c, \dots), Q(a, b, c, \dots), R(a, b, c, \dots), \dots\rangle$$ a *presentation of* $G$ and write $$G = \langle a, b, c, \dots; P, Q, R, \dots \rangle\,.$$</sub>

Comment: Your confusion stems from the word "if" which is not equivalent to "if and only if". That's all.

Comment: @studiosus: I don't have that confusion, nor I see anything in my post that would suggest that I do.  (And, BTW, if you're going to insult a poster's intelligence, please at least be more explicit about your reasoning.)

Comment: The relevant word "if" appears in your quotation of Exercise 4 (2nd paragraph of your post). The point is that the relation $a^2=1$ implies the relation $a^4=1$, but not vice verse ("if" is not the same as "if and only if").

Comment: I think the problem is this.  What you've shown in your derivation is that if $a^2$ were a relator, then $a^4$ is also a relator.  That does not show that $a^2$ is a relator in $C_4$. So, while $a^4$ is derivable from $a^2$, $a^2$ is not a relator, so doe not give a presentation of $C_4$.

Comment: There are two famous texts called "combinatorial group theory". The first by Magnus, karrass and solitar, the second by lyndon and schupp. I think Cohen had a book by this name also. So it is helpful to cite the authors when talking about these books! (I would guess MKS?)

Comment: @user1729: I figured that a hyperlink to the Google Books page for the book would give more than enough additional information.

Comment: Touche - I didn't notice the link. All the same, it is good practice to give the authors names (for there are people like me out there who do not notice links, for whatever unknown reason...).

Comment: @user1729: will do

Comment: @studiosus: I know that the relation $a^4 = 1$ does not imply the relation $a^2 = 1$.  Please show me is exactly where I wrote otherwise.

Comment: @Callus: Thanks, I think my error is along the lines of what you write in your comment, but when I re-read the bit in the book that gave rise to this question, I remain confused.  I give more details in the latest additions to my post.

Comment: Your post is getting a little long.  We should take the conversation out of the comments.  Try one of the chat rooms.  To answer though, what you're showing is that $a^4$ is a relator if $a^2$ is a relator, but just because $a^4$ is a relator doesn't mean the group is $C_4$.  In other words, $a^4$ is a relator in $\langle a; a^2\rangle$, but that doesn't mean that $\langle a; a^4\rangle$

Comment: @Callus: you're right; I really wish I could delete the post, and maybe do it over...

Comment: Having read your entire question, I cannot find a single piece of reasoning for why $\langle a;a^2\rangle$ is supposed to be a presentation for $C_4$...

Comment: @anon: the reasoning is exactly the same one that the authors give in the hint to exercise $5$(c).  In a nutshell: 1) pick some relators $x, y, z...$; 2) show that $b^4$ can be derived from $x, y, z, ...$; 3) then, by Exercise 4, $x, y, z...$ are defining relators of $C_4$.  Now, for my $x, y, z...$ I pick the single relator $b^2$, proceed to derive $b^4$ from it, and conclude that $\langle b; b^2 \rangle$ (i.e. $\langle a; a^2 \rangle$) is a presentation of $C_4$.

Comment: *"then, by Exercise 4,* $x,y,z,\dots$ *are defining relators of* $C_4$" How does that follow? Exercise 4 doesn't give you the power or authority to say that $b^4$ is a defining relator, it only says that derivability is transitive. Just because something can be derived from a defining set of relators does not mean that something is a defining relator $-$ in particular, just because $b^4$ is derivable from $b^2$ doesn't mean $b^4$ is also a defining relator for $\langle b;b^2\rangle$.

Comment: @kjo:  The mistake you keep making is that the text says "pick some relators...." and you are picking non-relators and then deriving $b^4$.  You have to start with some relators, and then derive the other defining set.

Comment: @anon: the "then by exercise 4 blah blah" bit comes basically verbatim from the book.  You can see the exact quotation in my post.

Comment: @Callus: You may be right.  I find the text very vague on the subject of picking relators.  For one thing, it discusses the defining of relators in terms mappings from sets of symbols to group elements.  If one uses the mapping $a \mapsto 2 \in \mathbb{Z}_4$, then $a^2 = 1$ (i.e. $2 + 2 = 0$ in $\mathbb{Z}_4$), so $a^2$ is a relator of the cyclic group of order $4$.  And I can derive $a^4$ from it.

Comment: Exercise 4 does **not** say "if $z$ can be derived from $x,y$ then $x,y$ is a defining set of relators for $\langle\text{blah};z\rangle$." Such a statement is obviously false. Instead, one might say something like "if two sets of words are each derivable from each other and the first set is a defining set of relators, then the second is also a defining set of relators" and then use this to show that $b^8,b^{12}$ is a defining pair of relators for $\langle b;b^4\rangle$. Either the sketch in Exercise 5 is wrong or it's supposed to read "*by a stretch of reasoning which includes Exercise 4*..."

Comment: @anon: the book (whether correctly or not) writes "...use $b^8$ and $b^{12}$ as defining relators, and show that $b^4$ can be derived. Hence, by the preceding exercise [i.e. exercise 4], $b^8$ and $b^{12}$ are a set of defining relators."  Are you saying the book is wrong, or are you saying that I am misinterpreting it?  (I figure it's the latter, but if so I have to concede that I just don't get it, and that it's completely beyond my ken.)  Anyway, thanks for your patience.  (And likewise to Callus too.)

Comment: @kjo: In your example, $a\to 2$, $a$ would not serve as a generator for $C_4$.

Comment: @Callus: OK!  I see!  That's it.  Thank you!

Comment: @kjo Either one is possible. Suppose I wrote "use $b^2$ as a defining relator, and show that $b^4$ can be derived. Hence, by the preceding exercise [i.e. exercise 4], $b^2$ is a defining relator [for $\langle b;b^4\rangle$]." Do you believe this? No, you don't; it's false. So there are only two possibilities left: the sentence was implying that while Exercise 4 is used it isn't the only reasoning involved in getting the conclusion, or the sentence is just flat-out false.

Comment: @anon: I see your point.  Also Callus just pointed out an even bigger hole in my reasoning.  I think that I can straighten out the mess in my head now.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

When you write $G=\langle a;a^2\rangle$, this is meant that $G$ is the group generated by an element $a$ such that $a^2=1$.  Notice that this means that $a=a^{-1}$.  So $G$ is just $\{1,a\}$.  For any $n\in\mathbb{N}$, the group $G=\langle a;a^n\rangle$ is just the group, $\{1,a,a^2,\ldots,a^{n-1}\}$, which is $C_n$.  In your case you have if $a^2=1$, then $(a^2)^2=a^4=1$, but not the other way around.  This is what @studiosus was getting at (I don't think his/her intent was to insult).

Comment: The thing is that it's not obvious to me that anywhere I've used the implication that $a^2$ is derivable from $a^4$.  BTW, I realize that there's something wrong with my argument, but this realization relies on too much prior knowledge about group theory.  The same is true of most of your answer.  I'm trying to think through this problem as if I did not know any other group theory beyond what the book has presented so far (i.e. very, very little).  Also, next time someone (a professor maybe, or a colleague) makes a error of arithmetic in a blackboard derivation, explain to them that the...

Comment: ...reason is that they are "confused about addition", or subtraction, or whatever the operation was where the misstep happened, and see if they don't take your "explanation" as an insult.

Answer (score 1):

The full statement of question $1.1.4$ is:

> Show that if the word $K$ is derivable from the relators $M,N,...$, and $M,N,...$ are derivable from the relators $P,Q,R,...$, then $K$ is derivable form $P,Q,R,...;$ hence if $M,N,...$ is a set of defining relators, then so is $P,Q,R,...$.

And here is the relevant part of the hint of $1.1.5(c)$, which will be the main example I will focus on (since that seems to be where your questions came from):

> Hint: For $(c)$ use $b^8$ and $b^{12}$ as defining relators, and show that $b^4$ can be derived.

If we follow the hint we need to note that we are assuming that $b^4$ is a set of defining relators (this is basically what is shown in part $(b)$ of the  same problem) and show that we can get $b^4$ from the given $b^8,b^{12}$. But we do not know a priori that $b^8$ and $b^{12}$ are relators of the group, so we can not apply problem $1.1.4$ yet. Of course it is a simple matter to show this, but this is where your analysis of the case of $b^n$ and $b^{n+4}$ fails, you never show that $b^n,b^{n+4}$ are relators, and for many $n$ they are not relators. A similiar problem occurs when you try to use $b^2$, or $b$ as relators, you don't know they are (and they obviously are not).

If I had to guess as to where you went wrong is that you were defining $b^2$ to be a relator, but when discussing relators we are working in a group , so there is a fixed set of relators, and just because you can get all the relators from $b^2$, that does not mean that it itself is a relator.